# Как вынести функцию в отдельный приватный метод

Tags: php, symfony2

Это все знакомый филд из `FormType Symfony`

```
  ->add('assignedAgents', EntityType::class, [
                'label'         => 'Agents',
                'multiple'      => true,
                'required'      => true,
                'class'         => 'Cirrus\UserBundle\Entity\User',
                'property'      => 'username',
                'attr'          => ['class' => 'select2'],
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('Usr')
                        ->orderBy('Usr.username', 'ASC');
                }
            ])
```

Как переделать `query_builder` в отдельный метод, чтобы `Coverage` тест написать на 100% =)

Есть ещё похожий вопрос без ответа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998640/unit-test-form-with-repository-method

Comment: а использовать `@codeCoverageIgnoreStart`/`@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd` нельзя? Тогда строки считались бы выполненными. Подробнее [здесь](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html)

Comment: неа на сервере пишет Lines:  93.88% ( 92/ 98) Подсвечены только эти функции

Comment: так вы отчет посмотрите, там подсветит что не посчиталось, у вас сейчас может в другом проблема, все-таки 6 строчек куда-то делось

Comment: не именно в этом, они и подсвечены, я просто привёл только одно место

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: @E_p не поможет =))) но вы мастер извращений

Comment: так вы в вопросе напишите как всем этим пользуетесь. Вы может `codeCoverageIgnoreStart` не так добавляете

Comment: @BOPOH Это не важно суть вопроса: как вытащить эти функции в отдельные методы класса

Comment: Вам подойдет решение предложенное @AmsTaFFix, если метод сделать публичным. Специфика callable хорошо описана по ссылке, которую предложил пользователь E_p. Пример рефакторинга в моем ответе ниже.

Comment: задавал вопрос давно, за это время научился делать правильно, в общем так не пишите как я в примере =) делайте через choice тогда все это можно будет пренести в helper, затем в репозитории  и нормально написать тесты

Answer (score 0):

По вопросу вы можете сделать так:

```
[$this, 'myPrivateMethod']
...
private function myPrivateMethod() {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ответ на вопрос как вынести функцию в приватный метод был дан пользователем @AmsTaFFix.

Хочу обратить ваше внимание на то, что польза от приватного колбека вне класса - нулевая: вы сделаете его недоступным для вызывающего кода. Результат будет ожидаем:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to private method ...
PHP Warning ... cannot access private method ...
```

Предложенное решение будет работать если сделать метод публичным:

```
class MyAwesomeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('assignedAgents', EntityType::class, [
            // ...
            'query_builder' => [$this, 'createQueryBuilder']
        ]);
    }

    public function createQueryBuilder(EntityRepository $repository)
    {
        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('Usr')
            ->orderBy('Usr.username', 'ASC');
    }
}
```